# How can I see automount points in Linux?

Tags: autofs

We use autofs at work and I'm having trouble remembering some mount points. With autofs, you can only see currently or recently mounted volumes on a particular machine. How can I see the rest?

Answer (score 19):

You can ask the root user to make the mount points always visible. This can be done by adding the following lines to `/etc/sysconfig/autofs`:

```
# BROWSE_MODE - maps are browsable by default.
BROWSE_MODE="yes"
```

Note: On recent Ubuntu versions the file is found at `/etc/default/autofs`

Answer (score 5):

You seem to mix up *devices* and *mount points* here. If a device is *not mounted* then it has no mount point associated. A mount point is nothing but a directory when not associated to a storage device.

If you want to list all mount points (that is, all mounted devices), use :

```
df
```

However, if you need a list of storage devices available, use :

```
fdisk -l
```

`fdisk` requires root privileges in most cases. If you don't have root privileges, you can list storage devices files beginning with `sd` in the `/dev` directory : this should give you enough information :

```
ls -l /dev/sd*
```

You can also read the `/proc/partitions` file :

```
cat /proc/partitions
```

Comment: any way to do it without root? I don't have it

Comment: I edited my answer with a solution which does not require root privileges. Note that `fdisk` (and other non-root tips) do **not** mention mount points, but only *devices*. `mount` and `df` will give you a list of *device/mount point* associations.

Comment: Not everything that can be mounted is a local device.

Comment: @guntbert The OP mentioned "mounted volumes on a particular machine", therefore I excluded NFS possibilities. Plus, these go a little beyond the simple use of `mount` and `fdisk`. Finally, I mentioned "storage devices" only, and not "devices" in general.

Comment: "autofs" to me generally implies remote media (NFS, SMB, ftp, ssh, ...) and removable local media - hence my point that the question cannot be answered with "the simple use of mount and fdisk" :-))

Comment: Yes these are NFS mounts from NFS servers. By that statement I just meant that on different machines you see different mounts, depending on which ones users on that machine happen to be using.

Comment: Then the use of `fdisk` isn't quite appropriate. You should add this information into your question.

Comment: I would like a way of seeing a stub for the mount point when the remote FS is not mounted. I can cause it to automount by typing 'ls /mnt/long_and_annoying_name' but I can no longer type 'ls /mnt/lo<TAB>' to have it autocomplete. (Alternately, can zsh autocomplete autofs mount points itself?)

Answer (score 3):

Just run 'mount' with no arguments. It will show you all mounted file systems. To my knowledge there is no way to see "historic" mount points other then somethings like `cat /var/log/messages | grep mount`. You will need to edit that last command quite a bit to get exactly what you want.

Comment: You could create a syslog entry for every mount attempt for autofs and review that. Config would be highly dependent on your syslogger.

Comment: I don't have root but I'd like to see a list of all devices that could be mounted and at which mount points if I knew what they were

Answer (score 3):

I see  the question is quite old, but the answers did not match, what I understood from it. This is for CentOS7 and probably RHEL.

You can `cat /etc/auto.master`. It will show you the defined mountpoints. There are although a couple of files in `/etc/auto.*`. These files are included by the `auto.master` and contain the subfolders, which will be automounted.